# Mount smb remote storage on debian with local disk caching using FS-Cache for CIFS

Tags: debian, cache, server-message-block, cifs

I am trying to connect a smb remote storage to my debian server and use the available space on the local disk as a cache using FS-Cache for CIFS. I have already tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work because the local disk space is not decreasing

```
 mount -t cifs -o ro,fsc,vers=3.0,user=xxxx,pass=xxxx, //xxxx.your-storagebox.de/backup /www/wwwroot/xxxx.com/samba
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same remote storage (which I fully recommend, by the way).

According to [the mount.cifs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs#:%7E:text=You%20also%20need%20to%20have%20cachefilesd%20daemon%20installed%20and%20running%20to%20make%20the%20cache%20operational.), *you also need to have [**cachefilesd** daemon](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/cachefilesd) installed and running to make the cache operational.* Also don't forget to enable it by editing `/etc/default/cachefilesd`